# React navigation keyboard hides bottom bar

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation v6. On any screen when the keyboard is opened by text input, the bottom navigation bar hides and I close the keyboard, it remains hidden.

**Before Image**

[image: Before Image]

When Keyboard opened

[image: WHen Keyboard opened]

**When keyboard is closed**

[image: When keyboard is closed]

Comment: it's seems like you are using a custom tabBar component, can u add any code so we can see what's wrong?